# Screen is tinting blue

Tags: display, external-display

"That" monitor is flickering on and off blue tint.

When I [Googled](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/253051-33-blue-tint) it, it seems it's a video card problem. The video card on my d620 is a nVidia Quadro NVS 110M w/ 64MB of memory, apparently running at a low 69 C.

I did all the obvious stuff (reboot, reset, etc.) and it seems to be somewhat stable now.

Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: When you say obvious stuff, did you check to ensure the cable is plugged in completely?

Comment: Yup. I even jiggled and and replugged it. Helped temporarily.

Comment: Is the cable running to the external monitor a serial connector, DVI, or HDMI? If it is one of the first 2 it could possibly be a cracked/loose pin in the connector. Test with another cable, if it is still happening with an undamaged cable than it is the output from the laptop itself.

Comment: @ricbax: When you say "serial connector" I think you mean "DB15" connector (technically a "DE15").

Comment: VGA. It's the only thing my computer supports.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: If we are getting technically specific, yes a S/VGA DE15 connector, it was late and I should have actually put "S/VGA connector".

Comment: @digitxp - Did you ever figure out what the problem was?

Comment: @ricbax Bad cable, bent pins. Who knew?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is indeed S/VGA than I would first check the cable specifically Pins 1,2,3 on the DE 15 male connector.

[image]

If any are loose, bent, or broken, swap the cable and see if that fixes the issue. If not, then it is the female DE15 port on the laptop that is the problem.

Comment: [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:DE15_Connector_Pinout.svg) is an link for the PNG version of the linked image for those of us that cannot load SVG images.

Comment: I doubt it, the cable is brand new and I didn't see any problem pins when I was unplugging it.